# Discord.js bot | Heroku deploy error | npm ERR! missing script: start

Tags: heroku, discord.js

Here is the Heroku logs;

```
2021-01-22T11:17:07.911108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-22T11:17:10.754315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-01-22T11:17:15.636637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2021-01-22T11:17:15.662837+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-22T11:17:15.673294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-22T11:17:15.673769+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T11_17_15_637Z-debug.log
2021-01-22T11:17:15.744906+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-22T11:17:15.806698+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-22T11:17:23.632780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hamburgerbot-djs.herokuapp.com request_id=5860703d-5eea-494e-b4d0-e052b7d90a44 fwd="176.41.220.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T11:17:24.442814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hamburgerbot-djs.herokuapp.com request_id=ec0558b8-95ce-43f3-b764-8bccdfc9cc4a fwd="176.41.220.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

How can I solve this error(s)?

Comment: It would be really useful if you could provide some code where you think this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might not have defined a `start` script in your `package.json` file. Due to this error: `2021-01-22T11:17:15.636637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start`

You could either change the name of your application script to `server.js` or add the following to your `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node your-script.js"
}
```